# Pass data back to previous view controller causing eroor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a view controller `HomeController` & `BookController`.I am going from view controller `HomeController` to `BookController`.I am passing data back to previous view controller.So i have used this approach.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BaseController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@protocol HomeProtocol
- (void)setComment:(BOOL)data;
-(void)setCommnetArray:(NSMutableArray*)data;
@end
@protocol BookProtocol
-(void)setBook:(BOOL)status;
@end
@interface HomeViewController : BaseController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,HomeProtocol,UIScrollViewDelegate,BookProtocol,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table_view;
@property BOOL hasUserPostedComment;
@property NSInteger commentIndex;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label_post_status;
@property UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
@property NSInteger start_offset;
@property NSInteger end_offset;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_refresh;
@property NSMutableArray *temp_user_cooments;
@property MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
@property BOOL isBookMarkLoaded;

@end
```

**BookMarkController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BaseController.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@protocol HomeProtocol
- (void)setComment:(BOOL)data;
-(void)setCommnetArray:(NSMutableArray*)data;
@end
@interface BookMarkController : BaseController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,HomeProtocol,UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BookProtocol> myDelegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table_view;
@property BOOL hasUserPostedComment;
@property NSInteger commentIndex;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label_post_status;
@property UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
@property NSInteger start_offset;
@property NSInteger end_offset;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_refresh;
@property NSMutableArray *temp_user_cooments;
@property MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
@property NSString *index;

@end
```

**Method implementation**

```
-(void)setBook
{
    NSLog(@"set book called");
    self.isBookMarkLoaded=true;
}
```

It gives error `Unrecognized selector sent to instance`.Please tell me what is the issue here.

Comment: You need to add protocol to the BookMarkController.h. But in your code you have declared the protocol in HomeViewController.h. So you are getting that error

Comment: You just need a protocol in BookController defined.

Comment: @Slavco Petkovski told you same thing. I had explain you step by step procedure, you need to follow the steps defined in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@protocol BookProtocol
-(void)setBook:(BOOL)status;
@end

Add above protocol to BookMarkController.h. Create delegate of the same in BookMarkController.h file. Make a call to -(void)setBook:(BOOL)status; from BookMarkController.m file

Add delegate in HomeViewController.h file. Define -(void)setBook:(BOOL)status; in HomeViewController.m file and also assign delegate to self.

That's all.

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem up vote for answer